# Laravel: Dingo API - NGINX 404 all routes

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, dingo-api

sorry if this a double post but I can't find the problem with this I installed Dingo api on a server with NGINX, PHP5.6 but everytime I access the server routes(e.g.http://104.27.5.XXX/api/brands) I always get

[image: 404 Error]

Here is the routes:

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');


$api->version('v1', function($api) {
    $api->get('/brands',function(){
        $brands = Brands::all();
        return $brands;
    });
    $api->post('/login','App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController@login');
    $api->get('/filters', 'App\Http\Controllers\FiltersController@index');
    $api->get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index');
    $api->get('/dashboard/brands/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@getBrandDrillDown');
    $api->get('/reports', 'App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@index');

});
```

Here is the .env file for the api config

```
API_STANDARDS_TREE=vnd
API_PREFIX=api
API_VERSION=v1
API_STRICT=false
API_DEBUG=true
```

Is there anything wrong???

added NGINX default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/hokair/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name http://xx.xx.xx.xx;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: whitout the nginx configuration we can't help you.

Comment: @Kbyte adding the nginx conf

Comment: @Kbyte done adding nginx conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nginx configuration is misconfigured.

Follow those instruction from the lavarel setup:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: There are no rewrite rules or index fallback in your nginx configuration. Every page xxx.xxx.xx.xx/* will return 404. Only xxx.xxx.xx.xx works because nginx executes index.php.

Comment: thanks thanks. I think I forgot the fundamentals and somehow instances like these make me look back at how I started with laravel :)